# Split file and know how many files were generated

Tags: shell, files, split

I'm using the following lines to split a file into smaller parts:

```
split --line-bytes=100M -d $input $output/FILENAME
echo "$input was split into ??? 100MB files." >> demo.log
```

After that, I need to write in a log file how many smaller files were generated from this split. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Use `--numeric-suffixes` and get the last file number..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply save the resulting pieces names in an array e.g.

```
splitarr=($output/FILENAME*)
```

and get the array length (number of elements) with `${#splitarr[@]}`. This assumes the only filenames matching that pattern are those produced by the `split` command.

---

You appear to be using `gnu split` so here are some other ways to do it: you could add the `--verbose` option (see `man` page for details) and just count the lines that `split` prints to `stdout` and save that into a variable:

```
ct=$(split --verbose --line-bytes=100M -d $input $output/FILENAME | wc -l)
```

You could get the same result with the less known option `--filter`:

```
ct=$(split --filter='printf %s\\n;cat >$FILE' --line-bytes=100M -d $input $output/FILENAME | wc -l)
```

Alternatively, if you know that only your `split` command will create files in that directory in the next `N` seconds you could use `inotifywatch` to gather statistics for e.g `close_write` event:

```
inotifywatch . -t 20 -e close_write
```

will watch the current dir for `close_write` events for the next 20 seconds and will output something like:

```
Establishing watches...
Finished establishing watches, now collecting statistics.
total  close_write  filename
11     11           ./
```

so it's only a matter of extracting that number from the table (e.g. pipe it to `awk 'END{print $2}'`; also keep in mind the first two lines are printed on `stderr`)